# How to SUM() multiple subquery rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

The question is simple: I want to do:

SELECT SUM((... a subquery that returns multiple rows with a single int value ...)) AS total;

How would I do that? I get an error saying that subquery returns more than one row. I need to have it in a subquery.

Answer (score 13):

Here's an approach that should work for you:

```
SELECT SUM(column_alias)
FROM (select ... as column_alias from ...) as table_alias
```

And here's a specific dummy example to show the approach in action:

```
select sum(int_val) 
from (
  select 1 as int_val 
  union
  select 2 as int_val 
  union 
  select 3 as int_val
) as sub;
```

Comment: nice answer! really helped

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just do the aggregation *within* the subquery?

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(...) ...) AS total,
    ...
```

(Untested!)

Comment: Not because I am using a GROUP BY and it thus SUMs too many rows.