# SUM using sub-query

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I would like using SELECT, inside SELECT to get some values (i allready done this).
Problem is,  i would like to display this data in mysql, sum, and that's the problem.

I won't post original code, but look at this example.

```
SELECT id, (SELECT COUNT(x) FROM xyz where id=usr.id) as value_1,
(SELECT COUNT(y) FROM zyx where id=usr.id) as value_2 
FROM users AS usr
```

That's work correct, but i would like to sum value_1 and value_2.

When i do this

```
SELECT id,
(SELECT COUNT(x) FROM xyz where id=usr.id) as value_1, 
(SELECT COUNT(y) FROM zyx where id=usr.id) as value_2, 
(value_1+value_2) as my_sum_value
FROM users AS usr
```

i got information about "value_1" and "value_2" not found.

I figure out, that i can use

```
SELECT id, 
(SELECT COUNT(x) FROM xyz where id=usr.id) as value_1, 
(SELECT COUNT(y) FROM zyx where id=usr.id) as value_2, 
((SELECT COUNT(x) FROM xyz where id=usr.id) as value_1, 
(SELECT COUNT(y) FROM zyx where id=usr.id)+
(SELECT COUNT(y) FROM zyx where id=usr.id) as value_2) as my_sum_value
FROM users AS usr
```

But, i have to write "twice" all of my code.
Why i can't use "alias"  called "value_1" and "value_2" ?
After query, this values are correct, how to access sum value?

Comment: Can you include your table schema?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785600/how-to-sum-multiple-subquery-rows-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT id,
    SUM(
    (SELECT COUNT(x) FROM xyz where id=usr.id), 
    (SELECT COUNT(y) FROM zyx where id=usr.id)
    ) as my_sum_value
FROM users AS usr
```

you can't use the variables because they're in a subquery...