# How to take sum of two different query result counts in mysql?

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I need to take total count of files from category + sub category + subsub category

For that I write this kind of a query using my views.

```
select ((select count(*) from view_category where 1=1)+ (select count(*) from view sub category where 1=1) + (select count(*) from view subsub category where 1=1)) as cnt
```

Its returning count value. But I want to know any other better method is available to get the same result.

I tried this way but its not working ([How to SUM() multiple subquery rows in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785600/how-to-sum-multiple-subquery-rows-in-mysql))

`select sum(int_val) from((select count(*) from view_category where 1=1) as int_val union (select count(*) from view sub category where 1=1) as int_val union (select count(*) from view subsub category where 1=1)  as int_val )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me

```
select count(*) from(
(select count(*) from view_category where 1=1) union (select count(*) from view sub category where 1=1) union (select count(*) from view subsub category where 1=1) ) AS int_val;
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to do a union, and can just have each as its own from alias... As long as each query is returning only one row, you can do all sorts of crazy things.  By ignoring any "join" condition, you get a Cartesian result, but a Cartesian of 1:1:1 will result with only 1 record

```
select
        ByCat.CatCount
      + BySubCat.SubCatCount
      + BySubSubCat.SubSubCatCount as Cnt
   from
      ( select count(*) CatCount
           from view_category ) ByCat,

      ( select count(*) SubCatCount
           from view_sub_category) BySubCat,

      (select count(*) SubSubCatCount
           from view_subsub_category ) BySubSubCat
```

Also imagine if you needed sum() or AVG() counts too from other elements...  You could get those into a single row and use however you needed.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables have similar structure, you might use `UNION` to unite the result and then perform one `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Just by intuition, I'd say summing three `COUNT` queries would be faster than taking a `COUNT` of an `UNION`.

Comment: yes that I know. but its three views. I dont want to join those views